# Java constructor overloading ambiguity

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

How to solve the following `constructor overloading` problem? This is an interview question but I am curious to know the solution.

```
class Player
{
    int nationalRank;
    int internationalRank;
    String name;

    Player(String name, int nationalRank)
    {
        this.name= name;
        this.nationalRank = nationalRank;
        this.internationalRank=0;
    }

    Player(String name, int internationalRank)
    {
        this.name= name;
        this.nationalRank = 0;
        this.internationalRank=internationalRank;
    }
}
```

Here, the compiler will give an error because argument types are same for both constructor. But logically they both are different. How can I solve this problem without adding any extra arguments? Is there any design pattern specifically for this?

Comment: How about a static factory method with a meaningful name for each option?

Comment: They have the same prototype, without changing arguments I can't see how you could do this, what are you allowed to do? Make subclasses maybe?

Comment: @Djon Yeah, I think I am allowed to make subclasses. Any solution would be preferred.

Comment: One simple but ambiguous solution would be to change the order of parameters `(int,String)` and `(String,int)`.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Yeah, but I don't think this solution will be preferred on a real project.

Comment: A static factory is what you need for real time project .

Comment: @GregKopff Can you give an example for it?

Comment: @AndroidDecoded see my answer for an example using a builder class

Comment: If you are allowed subclasses, you could have `NationalPlayer extends Player` and `InternationalPlayer extends Player`, each with one constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Player
{
    int nationalRank;
    int internationalRank;
    String name;

    private Player(){}

    public static Builder builder() 
    {
       return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder
    {
      int nationalRank = -1;
      int internationalRank = -1;
      String name;

      public Builder nationalRank(int nationalRank)
      {
        this.nationalRank = nationalRank;
        return this;
      }

      public Builder internationalRank(int internationalRank)
      {
        this.internationalRank = internationalRank;
        return this;
      }

      public Builder name(String name)
      {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
      }

      public Player build()
      {
        if (nationalRank == -1 && internationalRank = -1)
          throw new IllegalStateException("both ranks haven't been initialized");
        if (null == name)
          throw new IllegalStateException("name hasn't been initialized");
        Player result = new Player();
        result.nationalRank = this.nationalRank;
        result.internationalRank = this.internationalRank;
        result.name = this.name;
        return result;
      }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Player player = Player.builder().name("John").internationalRank(522).build();
```

Comment: +1 interesting. how it's pattern called? i think it's not just factory pattern.

Comment: I'd say it's a flavor of a Builder Design Pattern: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2012/06/builder-design-pattern-in-java-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You've got various options.

The simplest is to add factory methods like this:

```
public class Player
{
  private int nationalRank;
  private int internationalRank;
  private String name;

  private Player()
  {
  }

  public static Player newNationalPlayer(String name, int nationalRank)
  {
    Player nationalPlayer = new Player();

    nationalPlayer.name= name;
    nationalPlayer.nationalRank = nationalRank;
    nationalPlayer.internationalRank = 0;

    return nationalPlayer;
  }

  public static Player newInternationalPlayer(String name, int internationalRank)
  {
    Player internationalPlayer = new Player();

    internationalPlayer.name= name;
    internationalPlayer.nationalRank = 0;
    internationalPlayer.internationalRank = internationalRank;

    return internationalPlayer;
  }

  ...
}
```

However, this leaves an unused variable which isn't very nice.  A better solution would be to add a `PlayerType` enum:

```
public enum PlayerType
{
  NATIONAL,
  INTERNATIONAL
}

public class Player
{
  private int rank;
  private String name;
  private PlayerType type;

  public Player(String name, PlayerType type, int rank)
  {
    this.name= name;
    this.type = type;
    this.rank = rank;
  }

  ...
}
```

Which is best is down to the exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the parameters of one of the constructors and you are good to go....  I made this answer thinking that it's an interview question....perhaps the interviewer has this in mind...

```
 class Player
    {
        int nationalRank;
        int internationalRank;
        String name;

        Player(String name, int nationalRank)
        {
            this.name= name;
            this.nationalRank = nationalRank;
            this.internationalRank=0;
        }

        Player( int internationalRank,String name)
        {
            this.name= name;
            this.nationalRank = 0;
            this.internationalRank=internationalRank;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see what you did there.

Comment: Thats a good hack. But maybe can I get more generalized solution

Comment: Yes but he answered the question and I really did not see it coming.

Comment: @SamDufel but in interviews they check if the person has this kind of ability.....also...and that's an interview question...not a real project....if it's a real project we are not as restricted

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by a comment, just use static factory methods. In fact, this solution goes further than that and uses a builder. You will note a clear advantage: all instance variables are now final.

```
public class Player
{
    private final String name;
    private final int nationalRank;
    private final int internationalRank;

    // Constructor becomes private
    private Player(final Builder builder)
    {
        name = builder.name;
        nationalRank = builder.nationalRank;
        internationalRank = builder.internationalRank;
    }

    public static Builder withName(final String name)
    {
        return new Builder(name);
    }

    // Inner builder class
    public static class Builder
    {
        private final String name;
        private int nationalRank;
        private int internationalRank;

        private Builder(final String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Builder withNationalRank(int rank)
        {
            nationalRank = rank;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withInternationalRank(int rank)
        {
            internationationalRank = rank;
            return this;
        }

        public Player build()
        {
            return new Player(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Player player1 = Player.withName("foo").withNationalRank(1).build();
// etc
```